# Firebase Functions with NoSQL

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Store with the following Collections

```
Accounts
 - Account
  - Members
Users
 - User
  - Accounts
```

When I assign a User to an Account I want to add User to the Members Array *and* add the Account to the Users Accounts Array

Should I look to:

- Create a Function which updates both Collections (breaks single responsibility?)
- Handle the call to both the Accounts Collection and then User Collection in my Client?
- Use a Trigger to watch for a change in Account Members to update User?
- User a Trigger to watch User and update Accounts?

Comment: This sounds like a matter of opinion.  I suggest choosing the option that's most agreeable to your preferences and situation.  You don't even need a Cloud Function to do this - it could be handled on the client with a transaction as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no singular correct answer, but I usually look for a single point of definition. If that doesn't exist (as seems to be the case here), I often create it.

For example, you could introduce a `Memberships` collection, which it the only one the application code writes to, and then use Cloud Functions to fan out to `/Users/$User/Accounts` and `/Accounts/$Account/Users` from there.

Comment: Ah yes, this does seem to fit into other patterns I have seen - although I hadn't thought of it for this.

For completeness. I have started a Collection called Memberships and each document is something like this

Membership: {
"accountId": "1a2v3b"
"accountName":  "Acme Ltd",
"userId": "123",
"userName": "Bob McBob"
}

Does this align with your suggestion?